# Rodar aplicativos no Android Studio através do celular pelo USB

Tags: android

Alguém sabe como posso configurar o Android Studio para executar aplicativos no USB conectado no celular? Atualmente uso o GenyMotion e queria saber se existe algum problema de compatibilidade. 
Eu tentei alterar dentro de "run configurations" onde adicionei um novo dispositivo USB, mas quando clico em "run" ele não é exibido.

Comment: No seu disposito, configurou a opção de **Desenvolvedor**? Em caso afirmativo, marcou a opção de **USB Debugging**? Caso afirmativo, usando o **adb**, quando você usa `adb devices` com seu dispositivo plugado na USB, ele é listado?

Comment: @Wakim eu tenho um LG G2. Tem que deixar o celular como root? Pq nele não existe opção de desenvolvedor. Nas opções de USB não tenho isso. A parte do adb devices fica aonde? Lembrando que estou usando o Android Studio e não Eclipse. Obrigado.

Comment: Não precisa de root, basta clicar 7 vezes no **Build Number** nas opções do celular (hehe). Isso se aplica pra todas as IDE's e o **adb** fica na pasta **platform-tools** dentro do sdk do android. **devices** é um comando para listar os dispositivos conectados via USB e que estão disponíveis para uso para qualquer comando do **adb**.

Comment: @Wakim muito bom. Obrigado.

Comment: @Wakim uma resposta, eu queria votar na resposta, mas não existe ;)

Comment: sou iniciante nos estudos de android mas tive um problema parecido, e achei a solução no seguite video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1QkYd_QjEWc é bem curto sem audio e resolveu meu problema, espere que ajude :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Não precisa de root para debugar seu aplicativo em um dispositivo físico.

Para isso habilitar o modo debug, clicando *7* vezes no **Build Number** nas opções do celular.

Após habilitar basta marcar a opção **USB Debugging** dentro do menu **Developer Options**. Esses nomes podem variar conforme o modelo e linguagem do aparelho.

Com essa configuração feita. O teste mais simples é o comando `devices` do adb. O `devices` é um comando para listar os dispositivos conectados via USB e acessíveis ao *adb server*, isso é, que estão disponíveis para uso para qualquer comando do adb, incluindo *debug*.

Exemplo de execução:

```
wakim@wakim-Inspiron-5420:~$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
0432772433  device
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda!!!

Comment: como e onde eu faço esse teste?

Comment: @FabioHenrique, esse teste tem que ser feito no terminal com o adb no path do sistema.

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente é ter o modo debbug habilitado e o usb drive instalado no PC, e ao ligar o device o [Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) (**adb**) reconhece ele como device para debbug.
Mais info, em Inglês: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html